# Can't get correct internet ip by using c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I did try to get internet IP by using GetIp method (below) but it only get one IP that's **123.22.114.5** , I restarted my modem many times but it still **123.22.114.5**, please help me. (I'm using visual studio 2010 in windows 7 64bit)

(sorry about my bad english)

```
private string GetIp()
    {
        string extenalIp = "";
        string whatIsMyIp = "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp";
        string getIpRegex = @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string requestHtml = "";
        try
        {
            requestHtml = utf8.GetString(wc.DownloadData(whatIsMyIp));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do some thing with exception
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Regex r = new Regex(getIpRegex);
        Match m = r.Match(requestHtml);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            extenalIp = m.Value.ToString();
        }
        wc.Dispose();
        return extenalIp;
    }
```

Comment: You need to get the external ip, this question has a couple of solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/c-sharp-get-public-external-ip-address

Comment: What makes you think 123.22.114.5 is not your Internet IP?

Comment: David Schwartz: because that's not same with the ip when i visit whatismyip

Comment: @tainguyen: Do you have a proxy configured anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You would get just one IP which is your ISP's **external** IP address, when you request some external website like **whatismyip**.

All ISPs have limited static IP addresses and hosts facing the internet. 
That WAN IP address is shared among many users usually.

The IP you see there is completely **different** from your local IP address, and hence, restarting your modem won't change it.

Comment: Which IP are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: i want to retrieve the ip like what i see in whatismyip

Comment: i want to retrieve the ip like what i see in whatismyip (**184.95.55.21** is what i see in whatismyip but when i use this code, it just retrive **123.22.114.5**) what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you using some proxy in your browser? Your code appears all right and works fine for me.

Comment: i don't any proxy in my browser

Comment: Well, then there is no reason why a different IP is returned. Try fetching the same `whatismyip` home-page using your application code.