# How can i get the dynamic IP address assigned by my ISP using C#?

Tags: dynamic-ip

I have searched a lot to get this dynamic IP address assigned by my ISP using C#

none have turn out

So, how can i get the dynamic IP address assigned by my ISP using C# ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Get public/external IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/c-sharp-get-public-external-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Works by querying external websites like;

```
lynx --dump http://ipecho.net/plain
```