# How to get the public IP address of localhost using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My problem is that I have `127.0.0.1` but this is the private IP address of localhost.

How can I get public IP address of my localhost using C# asp.net?

Comment: Does your machine have it's own public IP address or are you going through a router? What exactly do you mean by "public"?

Comment: I m going through router. and run application in localhost

Comment: So you want the IP address of your router?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get my own IP address in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c) and a gazillion others

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7838551/1663001

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get public/external IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ip= host.AddressList.Where(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault();
```

**update**
you are looking for your public IP

to get it you should use http get to services like http://checkip.dyndns.org

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3253726/7724) answer that already exist in SO

Comment: using System.Net.Sockets;

Comment: I m getting {192.168.0.168}.but i think this not correct. when i check on google "What is my ip" its find 103.240.207.59.so how can find this .

Comment: @TarangGosai Like I sadi in my comment, you want the address of your router, not your machines IP address.

Comment: Yes,Router or ISP provider ipaddress?

Comment: @TarangGosai Your IP address is 103.240.207.59. If it changes, just ask here again and we'll tell you the new one.