# IP instead of localhost in URI

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

I am currently trying to create a valid link to a function of my API using this LOC:

```
Uri locationHeader = new Uri(Url.Link("GetUserById", new { id = user.Id }));
```

This returns the following:

```
http://localhost:53800/..../user/821105b1
```

However, as the link should be accessible from the network, I would need something like the following:

```
http://192.168.0.12:53800/..../user/821105b1
```

How can I get this result instead of the one with the localhost??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `0.12` your server's local ip address?

Comment: Change your project's Web setting URL to http://192.168.0.12:53800 might help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling local libraries will only give you the local IP. You can call an external API like whatismyip or checkip to get the external IP. See here...https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838551

Comment: I just need the LAN-internal ip, no external one. There is no local library that can manage that?