# How can i get the ip address of connection?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ip

I wanna know IP address of connection. Not Local IP.

Local IP: 192.168.#.#
WAN IP: #.#.#.#

You see your WAN IP at http://whatismyip.org

I tried this soution but that gives Local IP.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace FasterComputer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ip = Ipfind();
            Console.WriteLine(ip);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static string Ipfind()
        {
            if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                return "Disconnected";
            }

            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            return Convert.ToString(host
                .AddressList
                .FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "connection ip"?

Comment: I thinks he means his WAN ip

Comment: [Get public/external IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your public IP you **have** to go outside your network.  Why would your code implicitly know your *public* IP?

Thankfully you can use services like [icanhazip](http://icanhazip.com)

```
string publicIp = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
```

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful!