# Get Public client IP in C#/.net without external service

Tags: c#, .net, service, get, ip

How i get public client IP in C# without external api/service

I tried use this code. But, not success.

```
string ipAddress = Response.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        if(ipAddress == "::1")
        {
            ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1].ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
```

Comment: If you computer is behind DHCP, you need to use an external service. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253701/get-public-external-ip-address

Comment: Not DHCP, that's just auto assigning IP addresses. You mean NAT.

Comment: `::1` is localhost, and your code is correct, but you need to run your code on a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on ASP.NET Follow This Method:

```
Public string GetIp()  
{  
string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))  
{  
   ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];  
}  
return ip;  
}
```

otherwise use below method:

```
Public string GetIp()  {
        string IPAddress = "";
            IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
            string Hostname = null;
            Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
            Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
            foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
            {
                if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP);
                }
            }

            return IPAddress;
}
```

Please up-vote if you found this helpful.

Comment: The below method returns private client ip not the public one.